# Remote home, two desktops at the same time: firefox and thunderbird can't be run on both

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, firefox, thunderbird

We're using Ubuntu desktops with remote homes mounted via NFS. It's working ok overall, but we're facing a problem now with thunderbird and firefox.

Some users have two identical desktops running at the same time, they want to work locally on both, and they can't, mostly because some applications like Firefox and Thunderbird will bark at them for opening more than one session.

Comment: And what behavior do you expect ? if these programs requires that only one can access the email and cookie database, then locking is the only sane thing to do.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm trying to look for a workaround here. Maybe redirect firefox X window from one computer to another? Some kind of remote desktop login? Separate Firefox/Tunderbird profiles? So many choices, yet no one convinces me. Maybe there's something better out there, or someone can prove that one of that solutions is better than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Firefox have feature for sync, so you can move profile from /home to /usr/local and enable internal sync.